# How to add new Clustered Server to Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic, cluster-computing

In my **Eclipse Kepler**, I want to add a new Server (from Weblogic) at the **Servers View**. I can add my admin server domain, it is ok. But in my weblogic, I have a **cluster**, which has 2 servers also (`dev-server_01`, `dev-server_02`). How could set the Eclipse, to add the `dev-server_01` server from the cluster? If I try to add it from my domain's server location, it gives me error about he cannot find the **config.xml**, and I'd searched for this config.xml, but there is *only 1 config.xml*, under the domain root folder.

So. Is there any way to add a new clustered server to eclipse from weblogic, or the Eclipse can manage only the **AdminServer**? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe You are looking for a WTP for weblogic server.
Try out this website , maybe it can help.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/index.html